# How to update child value inside Firebase Database

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I want to Update emailid into firebase database. i have tried this code but data is not getting updated. can someone suggest me proper way to update data

```
ref.root.child("User Details").child(userId).observeSingleEvent(of: .childChanged) { snapshot in
            
            if snapshot.childrenCount > 0 {
                for user in snapshot.children.allObjects as! [DataSnapshot]
                {
                    
                }
            }
        }
```

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0EdrP.png)

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write

Comment: Maybe it helps:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642605/finding-it-difficult-to-update-value-in-firebase-in-swift or https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/ios/read-and-write#updating_or_deleting_data

Comment: Got the solution. Thank you